# Haskell Optarse Generic example failing on TypeOperators and DataKinds

Tags: haskell

I'm looking at this page on [optparse-generic](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-generic-1.1.4/docs/Options-Generic.html).

with this version of optparse:

```
$ stack install optparse-generic-1.1.4
optparse-generic-1.1.4: download
optparse-generic-1.1.4: configure
optparse-generic-1.1.4: build
optparse-generic-1.1.4: copy/register
```

When I try to run this sample code exactly as given:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators     #-}

import Options.Generic

data Example = Example
    { foo :: Int    <?> "Documentation for the foo flag"
    , bar :: Double <?> "Documentation for the bar flag"
    } deriving (Generic, Show)
```

I get:

```
<interactive>:10:14-56: error:
    Illegal operator ‘<?>’ in type ‘Int <?> "Documentation for the foo flag"’
      Use TypeOperators to allow operators in types

<interactive>:10:25-56: error:
    Illegal type: ‘"Documentation for the foo flag"’
      Perhaps you intended to use DataKinds

<interactive>:11:14-56: error:
    Illegal operator ‘<?>’ in type ‘Double <?> "Documentation for the bar flag"’
      Use TypeOperators to allow operators in types

<interactive>:11:25-56: error:
    Illegal type: ‘"Documentation for the bar flag"’
      Perhaps you intended to use DataKinds
λ>
```

As you can see, I have both DataKinds and TypeOperators enabled.  How can I debug what's happening here?

Comment: How are you loading the file? The `<interactive>` parts of the error message makes me think that you are inputting the example in a GHCI session directly, are you sure the extensions are on? (The example works fine when loaded from a file on my end)

Comment: Loaded a file with the parts above the `data Example` definition.  Entered the second part in ghci.

Comment: If it's all in a file, everything's fine.  But I can't test and define these datatypes in ghci?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that GHCi does not inherit the extensions from the file you loaded.

To see which extensions are loaded in GHCi use `:show language` and to enable an extension, for example `TypeOperators`, use `:set -XTypeOperators`.

There is a feature request (GHC ticket [#11469](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11469)) to make GHCi include language extensions from the loaded file, but it seems to have little recent activity.

Comment: Huh. So when have overloadedstrings, etc. and I'm working on an interactive session, I have to always start by re-declaring those, even if I source a file where they're declared?

Comment: Seems to be that way currently, I must say I was surprised! See the linked ticket for how this could change in the future (note that the original proposal was written 8 years ago.)

Comment: Fascinating.  (1) In the course of Haskell development, do you just have a workflow that doesn't use ghci at all, or do you find yourself always importing the same set of stuff at the start of interactive sessions?  (2) can this really be so?  I feel like I've not redundantly declared OverloadedStrings in ghci, but have been able to test things using it, I think?

Comment: (1) I use GHCi constantly, with the help of the emacs mode `haskell-mode`, which essentially loads files like `:load file.hs` does. (2) I can't remember any troubles with OverloadedStrings either... Strange!

Comment: I signed up for the GHC trac and added a comment linking to this question on that ticket.  Thank you for your help. https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11469#comment:4